# nsobject dealloc never called

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, dealloc

I create an object in each iteration of a `for` loop. However the dealloc function is never called. Is it not supposed to be released at each iteration? I am using ARC and I have NSZombies deactivated. I don not see either any circular reference. Running the memory leak instruments from xcode it does not show any leaks, however the pointers memory of the class are never freed and the `dealloc` call never done. Any idea why this could happen?

Thank you!

```
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
    //calculate the hog features of the image
    HogFeature *hogFeature = [self.image obtainHogFeatures];
    if(i==0) self.imageFeatures = (double *) malloc(hogFeature.totalNumberOfFeatures*sizeof(double));

    //copy the features
    for(int j=0; j<hogFeature.totalNumberOfFeatures; j++)
        self.imageFeatures[i*hogFeature.totalNumberOfFeatures + j] = hogFeature.features[j];
}
```

The `HogFeature` class declaration looks like this:

```
@interface HogFeature : NSObject

@property int totalNumberOfFeatures;
@property double *features; //pointer to the features 
@property int *dimensionOfHogFeatures; //pointer with the dimensions of the features

@end
```

and the implementation:

```
@implementation HogFeature

@synthesize totalNumberOfFeatures = _totalNumberOfFeatures;
@synthesize features = _features;
@synthesize dimensionOfHogFeatures = _dimensionOfHogFeatures;

- (void) dealloc
{
    free(self.features);
    free(self.dimensionOfHogFeatures);
    NSLog(@"HOG Deallocation!");
}

@end
```

Finally, the call to `obtainHogFeatures` inside the `UIImage` category looks like:

```
- (HogFeature *) obtainHogFeatures
{
    HogFeature *hog = [[HogFeature alloc] init];
    [...]
    return hog;
}
```

Comment: did your self.image is released/set to nil? where did you do it?

Comment: do you have ARC enabled?

Comment: It's clearly stated in the question that ARC is being used.

Comment: What happens if you change the function name from `obtainHogFeatures` to `createHogFeatures`?

Comment: @iain: I agree, the name was not choosen well.

Comment: @vodkhang: self.image is not set to nil because I need it later on.

Comment: @mingot did you try to change it? ARC bases its release/retain semantics on the method names, and so they need to follow the Cocoa naming system: methods that return allocated memory are called newSomething or createSomething

Comment: Here are the Cocoa memory management naming conventions: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to enclose the inner loop with an `@autoreleasepool { ... }` which tells the compiler when to do the disposal, otherwise the pool will only be emptied when control returns to the main loop.

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        ...
    }
}
```

As pointed out by CodeFi in the comments:
This will create a new autoreleasepool for each iteration of the loop, which would destroy each object after the iteration is completed, but would make the program do more work. If you don't mind all the objects hanging around until after the loop is completed, you would put the `@autoreleasepool` outside of the outer loop

```
@autoreleasepool {
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Actually, `@autoreleasepool`s go ***outside*** loops so they can collect the objects allocated within the loop.  This will spawn 10 different autoreleasepool calls.

Comment: And that appears to be what he wanted...the HogFeature to be deallocated at the end of each iteration of the loop. But yes, if he doesn't mind the 10 objects hanging around until the end of the for loop, you'd put the `@autoreleasepool` outside the loop

Comment: Then this is sort of what he wants.  We have no control over autoreleasepool drains with that compiler directive.  If he wants a deallocation, he should use an explicit release.  This will add 10 objects to the autoreleasepool, but it makes no guarantee that, say, no more than one object will be alive at any same time.

Comment: but I'll edit my answer to highlight your point, because it is valid

Comment: Using @autoreleasepool to destroy transient objects from each loop iteration is practically the reason it exists. Putting it outside the loop is bizarre.

Comment: @Catfish_Man I suppose if the rest of the code after the loop was memory intensive or a long time running, then you might want to get the objects destroyed before that, but not care about them being destroyed each loop iteration.

Comment: Does this really answer the question though? The OP is wondering why the objects aren't being released by ARC. Isn't throwing them in an autorelease pool only suggesting that ARC should do what it already should be doing but in a smaller scope? It seems to me that the autorelease pool should only result in a quicker release than would otherwise happen, it should not in and of itself induce a release.

Comment: @isaac hmm, you're right I guess. Doesn't ARC use function names to work out semantics, and `obtain` is not an Apple semantic trope. What would happen if it was changed to `createHogFeatures`?

Comment: Frankly I'm confused by the malloc and attempted free calls -- it's hard to tell what's an array here or decipher these data structures. My guess is that these objects (the hogFeature) are going into an array and not coming out, hence, they'll be retained by that array as long as it lives or until they are removed).

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was looking for! Autorelease pool inside the loop. The problem I have is that some malloc where not releasing inside the loop and as the features are very large, it resulted in not enough memory.Sorry all for the confusing code, I tried to simplify it but I recognize it is confusing. I had to use c like arrays instead of NSArray or more high level structures for perfomance issues.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the objects are sticking around is because they aren't being released. I don't see the declaration of self.imageFeatures - is this an array? If the features are being put in to an array, they won't be released as long as they remain in the array or the array itself isn't released.

I'm a little confused by the use of the C malloc and (attempted) free calls. There may very well be a motivation here I'm not aware of, but, given what you have provided, here is how I would write this, and I'd be surprised if the deallocs aren't triggered as expected:

```
    NSMutableArray *features = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        NSArray *hogFeatureArray = [[self image] obtainHogFeatures];
        for (HogFeature *feature in hogFeatureArray)
        {
            [features addObject:hogFeature];
        } 
    }

    [self setImageFeatures:features];
```

The imageFeatures property is:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *imageFeatures;
```

Assuming you've put all your hog feature instances into this imageFeatures array, they will be retained by that imageFeatures array. In order to observe your dealloc in action, one of two things needs to happen: You either need to remove a hog feature from the array, or you need to release the array itself (this would be done by setting the pointer to nil):

```
[self setImageFeatures:nil] // Previously assigned array now released
[[self imageFeatures] removeAllObjects]; // Works alternatively
```

Comment: self.imageFeatures is a double array (C like) and it stores the concatenated hogFeature.features for the distinct images. It is allocated in the first piece of code. I use double* C like arrays instead of NSMutableArray for performance. I use free to free the double arrays of the HogFeature object. If I do not find the answer without using NSArrays for the features, I will try your approach. Thank you!

Comment: While C will give you better performance, you take on the responsibility for managing memory, because ARC is only responsible for Objective-C objects http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#general . Personally my advice would be to implement this in Objective-C, and only fall back to C if the performance is sufficiently lacking (again, I don't know what you've already tried... but we all know the adages of premature optimization!). Good luck.